# Splitting the relative tangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}(E\oplus O_X)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Suppose $X$ is a smooth scheme and $E$ is a vector bundle on $X$. We have an exact sequence
$$0\to T_{\mathbb{P}(E)/X}\to T_{\mathbb{P}(E\oplus O_X)/X}|_{\mathbb{P}(E)}\to O_E(1)\to 0.$$
Does this sequence split? I know this is true when $E$ is trivial. How about the general cases?

Comment: Doesn't the Euler vector field yield a splitting?

Comment: @FriedrichKnop Indeed, thx.

Comment: @FriedrichKnop: What do you mean by the Euler vector field — say on $\Bbb{P)^n$?

Comment: The vector bundle $E$ is an open subset of $\mathbb P(E\oplus\mathcal O_X)$ and carries a $\mathbb G_m$-action. Its Lie algebra acts via the Euler vector field. That should induce a splitting since it is transversal to $\mathbb P(E)$.